# Bypass passport authentication during end to end testing

Tags: authentication, testing, passport.js, puppeteer, gui-testing

I'm currently testing an internal company app (react-redux-express) and wanted to include some UI tests using Puppeteer (the rest of my tests are build with Jest and Enzyme). When I start a Puppeteer page, the session is not logged in and gets redirected to a Google sign-in page via our passport.js middleware. However, my problem is that sometimes our company specific google log in requires 2-factor authentication and therefore blocks any meaningful UI tests from accessing the actual application. So my question is whether there is a way to use passport middleware to exempt auth for testing only, and if so, is that a wise move to make or will it cause security issues?

Answer (score 1):

Our current method of choice is to have a middleware that just monkey patches the user used by Passport.

```js
const mockMiddleware = (req, _, next) => {
  req.user = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    ...
  };
  req.isAuthenticated = () => true;
  next();
};
```

And then we can conditionally include this *after* defining all our passport/session middleware:

```js
if(shouldMockAuthentication){
    app.use(mockMiddleware)
}
```

As an extra security step you want to probably only mock if something cannot be true during production (like running on `localhost` or something) so that it can absolutely never happen in prod.